# Is a 429 appropriate for email flood control?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Our site includes the ability for users to email a link to any email address they want. We're implementing flood control to stop malicious users from sending more than a few emails a day.

I'm trying to determine the best status code to return when flood control is tripped. The closest thing I could find is 429, "Too Many Requests." Would that be appropriate for this situation, or is there something better?

Thanks!

Comment: "The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time. Intended for use with rate-limiting schemes.". Would be hard to find something better me thinks.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Good stuff! I wasn't sure if "rate control" was a technical term that I would be abusing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status code 429 is the most appropriate for rate limiting.

```
429 Too Many Requests (RFC 6585)
The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time. Intended for use with rate-limiting schemes.
```